# Pandas replace dataframe value with a variable at a variable row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a row in a csv file with a variable. The row itself also has to be a variable. The following code is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c'], 'B':['b','c','d']})
print("Original DataFrame:\n", df)

x = 1
y = 12698

df_rep = df.replace([int(x),1], y)
print("\nAfter replacing:\n", df_rep)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using pandas indexing eg `df.iloc[row_num, col_num]`.

```
#update df
df.iloc[x,1]=y

#print df
print(df)
   A      B
0  a      b
1  b  12698
2  c      d
```